# TailwindCSS grid columns falsely align as rows

Tags: html, tailwind-css

I want to create a grid layout with tailwind css.

```
<h1 class="text-8xl text-blue-500 font-extrabold">Hello World.</h1>
<p class="text-slate-600 font-extralight">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<div class="grid grid-cols-4">
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>
  <div>Three</div>
  <div>Four</div>
  <div>Five</div>
  <div>Six</div>
  <div>Seven</div>
  <div>Eight</div>
</div>
```

Note the `h1` and `p` tags are only used to demonstrate that tailwind (seems to be / is) configured properly.

**Expected Result (can be verified using tailwind playground):**
[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6X4K.png)

**Actual Result**
[Actual Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KF6aK.png)

Does anyone know a solution to that issue? Could there be something wrong with my configuration? Let me know.

I tried various versions of creating a grid using the tailwind css grid property in tailwind playground. When applying that code to my website i receive columns configured as rows.

Comment: Seems your configuration is wrong here is your code in [Tailwind playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/XMPADLTBSU)

Comment: your code exactly shows as your expected result for me too